# codeigniter redirect fails only when i include "refresh"

Tags: php, codeigniter, redirect, controller, codeigniter-2

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class VerifyLogin extends CI_Controller
{

 public function __construct()
 {
    parent::__construct();
    //Model for fetching users in database
    $this->load->model('user', '', TRUE);
 }                             


 public function index()
 {
    //Load method to help verify form credentials
    $this->load->library('form_validation');

    //-----------------------------------------------
    //Verify Existance of values in login form fields
    //-----------------------------------------------
    //Validate existance of username field value
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Username', 'trim|required|xss_clean');
    //Validate existance of password field value, and if exists then call 'check_database' func
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'trim|required|xss_clean|callback_check_database');

    //If the form validation is false (i.e. Missing form fields)
    if($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE){
            //Redirect back to login page
            $this->load->view('general-Login');
    }
    //Login Success, goto main-page
    else{
        //Go to main page
        redirect('Main', 'refresh');
    }
}

function check_database($password)
{
    //Field validation succeeded.  Validate against database
    $username = $this->input->post('username');

    //Check the username and password against database
    $result = $this->user->login($username, $password);

    //If there is a result
    if($result){
        //will be used for session information
        $sess_array = array();
        foreach ($result as $row){
            $sess_array= array(
                'id' => $row->id,
                'username' => $row->username
            );
            //Session set as logged in
            $this->session->set_userdata('logged_in', $sess_array);
        }
        return true;
    }
    //No existance of user or, incorrect password
    else{
        //Send Message of incorrect username or password
        $this->form_validation->set_message('check_database', 'Invalid Username or Password');
        return false;
    }
}
}
```

So i have a verifylogin controller that handles the form data from my login page. Database access works great and everything works perfectly until i get to the redirect feature. I try to redirect with refresh and it just gives me a page that says "undefined". Now it will suddenly work when i remove the 'refresh' and just leave the controller name, but i'm trying to figure out why this 'refresh' won't work.

I've disabled my `.htaccess` 
I've tried setting my `$config['uri_protocol']` to `REQUEST_URI`, `AUTO`, and `PATH_INFO`
  and had no luck.

Also, this is my first submission online to anything like a forum so please....be gentle.

Answer (score 1):

First off, welcome to Stack Overflow.

Secondly, if redirect() without the "refresh" works, I would run with it and figure it out later.

For a deeper explanation, "refresh" attempts to do a meta-like refresh to the page similar to:

> `<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;URL='http://example.com/'">`

(**Note:** It doesn't do that within your view, but rather sends the browser a similar snippet in the response)

What browser are you using? What version? Hopefully it's something up-to-date, because that could make a difference in how the refresh works.

Answer (score 1):

I had similar problem. E.g. on my localhost refresh do not work and on the hosting provider settings it works. Maybe something in Apache/PHP configuration. Go without refresh, it is OK. I do not think it has something to do with a browser. I was using the same browser when that happened.